# $ f_3(a,b) $ always a cube integer?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, cubics, vieta-jumping

Consider rational functions in two positive integer variables $a,b$ with integer coëfficiënts : $f_i(a,b)$.

Some of them have special properties.

For instance

$$ \frac{a^2 + b^2}{1 + ab} = f_2(a,b) = c $$

It is obvious that $c$ is a positive fraction.

But the special things here are :

Property A2 : whenever $c$ is an integer , it is a square integer.

Property B2 : every integer square has at least one representation of the form $f_2(a,b)$.

We can easily prove property A2 with the famous vièta jumping technique.

Now im looking for such a rational function $f_3(a,b)$ such that

$$ f_3(a,b) = d $$

where $ d $ is always positive and we have the following properties :

Property A3 :  whenever $d$ is an integer , it is a cube integer.

Property B3 : every positive integer cube has at least one representation of the form $f_3(a,b)$.

Does such a rational function $f_3(a,b) $ even exist ?

How to decide existance ?

Assuming existence , is there uniqueness up to substitions $a,b$ to $x(a),y(b)$ where $x,y $ are integer polynomials ?
( replacing $f_3(a,b)$ with $ f_3(x(a),(y(b))$ is also a solution in many cases )

Can we construct such a solution ?

Comment: “I think we should give special recognition to the eleven students who have solved this problem well, in view of the fact that outstanding specialists in Numbers failed to do the same”. This was what the German delegate at the 1988 IMO said about problem No. 6 in Canberra, Australia which could not be solved by prestigious specialists in number theory. Said problem 6 is your A2 property. This problem is not so easy as you say.

Comment: Despite the initial difficulty , after knowing about vieta jumping A2 is in fact trivial.  Do you have An easy proof of B2 ? In general cubics and generalizations are harder than squares ..

Comment: I held the paper The Diophantine Equation $\dfrac{x ^ 2 + y ^ 2}{1 + xy} = z ^ 2$ at an international congress in Riga and I resolved the thing there. Based on that I think that with cubes the problem must be more difficult but do not believe me.

Comment: So basicly , piquito tells me he proved property B2. Right ? Of did he only discuss it. Who proved B2 first anyway ?  I would like to see that Paper !!                                          
  Like I said before cubes are usually harder than squares ... Both in number theory and algebra ... So no surprise there imho.                                                                                   Btw i wonder if proving property A2 can be done without vièta jumping ??                        Maybe worth a new question on MSE of MO.

Comment: No, I have not proved B2, what I have done is to show that there are an infinity of solutions of the mentioned diophantine equation (others have done it differently). I allow myself to doubt that B2 is true. I would also like to see your Vieta jumping making the A2 demonstration "trivial". I do not think so due to the difficult "nature" of the problem (sorry for bad English).

Comment: Note anyway that all square $n^2$ has a trivial representation with $(x,y)=(0,n^2)$ since $n=\dfrac{0^2+n^2}{1+0\cdot n}$

Comment: A trivial solution is $f_3(a,b)=a^3$, and variations thereof.